# Set up public ip on server

Tags: routing, port-forwarding

I am not quite sure if this should belong here but how do I add public ip to my server?

I wanted to launch a system in Server B live to internet. The problem is no physical connection is linked between my server(Server A) and the Server B.

What I noticed with Server B was:

- the server is using dynamic ip
- the server is located on the other street so cabling is not an option
- it has a default gateway 192.168.0.70.1
- I also noticed that only those PC's connected to the wifi was able to connect to the system.

I have read somewhere that assigning Public IP and Port Forwarding to Server B will probably help me launch that system live to the internet.

The problem is I have little/to no knowledge at networking and every term is like a puzzle to me.

Comment: The first step is to ask your ISP to assign you a public IP address if they don’t give you one by default. It might be either static or dynamic (accessible from outside but not guaranteed to be constant). This and many more things will influence further steps (see [Mikael’s answer](https://serverfault.com/a/961975/223390)). Unfortunately, this question cannot be answered generally.

Comment: It is also very unclear what the link to Server A is. You just mention it's not linked to Server B, but don't say a word about how is should be interacting with it (if at all). Which makes me think you could even be looking at VPN between A & B, and something like giving external access to Server B from Internet (might be achieved thru port forwarding on some your consumer grade router)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Presenting a service to the Internet definitely should not be done unless you know what you're doing. Fortunately it's mostly a matter of not being naïve, but you definitely should have passed a certain threshold of knowledge before you attempt this.

Assuming you're the single person who will have to manage this solution, here are some concepts with which you should be somewhat familiar before attempting to set up a public server:

- Network firewall concepts and rules.
- IPv4 routing.
- DNS and Dynamic DNS
- Securing Internet traffic using TLS
- TLS Certificates and their management

Tip: Practice these things in a test environment separate from your production environment. If money is an issue, you can "invest" in a test environment as small as a regular home DSL router and a Raspberry Pi, as long as you have access to a public IP.
And since this is supposed to be an Internet facing production service, don't skimp on your training. Nobody will thank you for it.

Comment: Well I have done all of these things. I am just poor at doing network. I am scared of hitting an IP Address if ever I will set a Public IP

Comment: @marvincastro: "Hitting an IP address"? What does that even mean? If you mean "using an IP address that's already in use by someone else", then Stop.Right.Now. I agree with this answer (+1), you need to understand Internet Technology to a much better level if you want to safely put something on the Internet that won't be hacked in minutes. I'm serious; that is the time it takes to break into an unsecured server on the 'Net.

Comment: @marvincastro: I'm really not a proponent of "easy" answers to this sort of question, because doing these things well does require a small but solid set of knowledge in a number of areas (see my earlier post), and the only good way of achieving that is through reading and practice. It doesn't have to be expensive, but it has to be allowed to take some time.

Comment: can anyone recommend some resources for these 5 concepts?

Comment: @marvincastro: unfortunately, Mikael H is right. I think I understand what you mean by "hitting an IP address", you probably mean using one that is already in use. This would cause absolutely no problem to anyone but you, for the simple reason that things work differently: your ISP would give you an IP. If you try using another, nobody will reach your machine, and the fact you don't understand this shows that you don't have proper knowledge of routing.

Comment: @user1532080: Unless the ISP just puts all nearby customers in a shared subnet and relies on ARP responses being honest...

Comment: @MikaelH, I think port forwarding should be added to your list.

Comment: @Ben, Yes, although I considered that a subset of both firewall rules and IPv4 routing. :)

Comment: @grawity: then you would need to choose an IP from that subnet, and not just a random one, unless the ISP also has a mechanism to update routing tables based on ARP.

Comment: Thank you guys for the concern. I guess I need to read more than what I am currently doing. Everything in here will be acknowledged and be subject for immediate studying. Thanks.